# How do i make set a maximum for a variable?

Tags: java, netbeans, int, limit

How do i set a maximum number so that a certain variable cannot exceed it's limit in my code, the player can repeatedly go to heal therefore their health becomes more than their maximum HP

```
public class HEAL {
    public static int maxhp = 25;
    public static int hp = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        heal();
    }

    public static void heal() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Would you like me to heal you? \n[1] Yes\n[2]No");
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if (choice == 1) { 
            System.out.println("You have been healed for 10 hp");
            HEAL.hp = HEAL.hp + 10;
            System.out.println("Your current HP: "+HEAL.hp);
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            System.out.println("Leave");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried anything on this front?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a function setHp, which would check if it is within the constraints.

```
if (val < 0 || val > 100) {
     /* not within constraints, do what you want here */
  } else {
  hp = val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make the variable hp private and 2nd, handle internally in the object if and when to increment it.
This

[1]

```
private static int hp=10;
```

[2]

```
public incrementHealPoints(int _hp){
  if(this.hp < HEAL.maxhp){
    this.hp += _hp;
  }else{
    // just ignore? maybe raise an error or log this?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (added `if` to check if `hp` exceeds 25) :

```
HEAL.hp=HEAL.hp+10;
if (HEAL.hp>25) //add this in your code
HEAL.hp=25;
System.out.println("Your current HP: "+HEAL.hp);
```

> Set value of variable `hp` as 25 if it exceeds 25 (since 25 is the
>   maximum limit).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.min`:

```
HEAL.hp = Math.min(HEAL.hp + 10, 25)
```

Where `25` is the maximum health.

Answer (score 0):

I added some explanations in the comments to the proper lines:

```
if((HEAL.hp + 10) >= HEAL.maxhp) { // If HEAL.hp after adding 10 would be equal or greater than HEAL.maxhp...
    HEAL.hp = HEAL.maxhp; // Assign HEAL.maxhp value (it's 25 in your example) to HEAL.hp
} else { // Otherwise...
    HEAL.hp = HEAL + 10; // Add 10 to HEAL.hp
}
```